# Top menu bar and padding-top when resized?

Tags: html, css

I have a top menu bar that is in position fixed and contains some text.  When the screen is resized smaller it compresses and it's height increases to fit the text.

I have a div below the top menu bar that contains my website content, moved down using padding-top.

When the top menu bar resizes the top of the article gets covered by the height change of the top menu bar.

```
#topmenubar{position:fixed;width:100%;text-align:center;word-wrap:normal;}

#content {padding-top:40px;}
```

What is the best way around this so the resized top menu bar does not cover my content?

The Top menu bar has to always be visible at the top of the screen, so I guess how can I make the padding-top get bigger with the screen width getting smaller or another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure JavaScript solution (no jQuery required):

```
window.onresize = function() {
    document.getElementById("content").style.paddingTop = document.getElementById("topmenubar").offsetHeight;
};
```

Comment: @David19801 If it worked for you, click the tick next to this answer to mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2):

#### jquery

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var h = $("#topmenubar").height();
  $("#content").css("padding-top",h+"px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by removing width 100% to some fixed pixel width so that top menubar will not resize,
 or at some extent by min-width property.

Comment: If I do that the text in the top menu bar will flow off the edge of the page right?

Comment: If you set a `min-width`, then that introduces a scrollbar on resize (when making window smaller) or makes part of the menu bar inaccessible when setting `overflow: hidden` on the page.

Comment: Of course some contents flow off the edge, if he don't want to let this happen then surly he/she has to add top padding/margin to below contents on re-size as told by Dariush and Abody97.